# "Format Document" command doesn't format JSON

Tags: visual-studio, json

I have a JSON document opened in Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10. I am trying to format the document using the "Format Document" command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). When I do that I get the following message:

> The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format Document) which is not currently... (*Cant find the rest of the sentence*)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem listed at
[JSON formatting is broken when using all TAB indents, nested objects and arrays all inside a file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/219415/json-formatting-is-broken-when-schema-is-set-to.html).

A known workaround is to replace tabs by spaces.
Enter the menu *Tools > Options > Text Editor > JSON > Tabs*,
and enable "Insert spaces".

Comment: Thanks. I do not have "JSON" under "Text Editor".

Comment: This option is then missing on Community. Because there is a common code between the two versions often the bugs are shared, but the interface is not identical. On my computer the settings for JSON are kept in the registry, but for Visual Studio they are in an area that is out of bounds even for administrators, and I haven't managed to crack it. If for Community this is less-well protected, search your registry for items named exactly "Insert Tabs" (without quotes) and see if they are accessible for you.